# preg_match whole XML File?

Tags: php, regex, xml, preg-match

Hey there I have a little problem. I tried to preg_match a whole xml file for specified words but it doesn't work

my xml:

```
 <product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
 </product>
```

And i would like to cut and remove certain words out of the whole file using preg_match.

my php:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
   $var = $xml->product[$i];
   if (preg_match_all('/\b(\w*Test\w*)\b|\b(\w*Black\w*)\b/', $var, $result)){
      do something 
   }
```

But it doesn't work only when i replace

```
  $var->$xml->product[$i];
```

with

```
$var->$xml->product[$i]-> Specifications->item;
```

it matchs Test

How can i fix that i am out of ideas
Thanks for help!

Comment: All I can suggest is look into XPATH to help locate your elements better.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess around with regular expressions, try a parser instead:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<DATA
 <product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
 </product>
DATA;

# set up the DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("*[contains(., 'Test')]") as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
?>
```

This yields all tags having `Test` as text somewhere.

---

The snippet sets up the `DOM` and uses `xpath` queries to look for the appropriate items which you can then loop over.

---

To have multiple strings you want to look up, use an alternation:

```
foreach ($xpath->query("*[contains(., 'Test') or contains(., 'Black')]") as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: `$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('Test.xml');

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);` I tried it with that but it doesn't work?

Comment: the error is: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1

Comment: @NeunNatter: `loadXML()` expects a string, you need `load()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way is to use xpath, like also suggested by others.

To strictly respond to your regexp question: your problem seems to be caused by the fact that `preg_match_all` will search only the first line of subject by default. You can use the `s` modifier to extend this to all of your multiline string:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(\w*Test\w*)\b|\b(\w*Black\w*)\b/s', $var, $result)
```